# Flutter How to using text field inside ListTile?

Tags: layout, dart, tableview, textfield, flutter

I wanna implement a ListTile which in the tailing is a textfield, this is something like iOS static tableview, so that users can click it and directly edit text.
How to do this in Flutter anyway?

Answer (score 11):

For the future people may also have this trouble, here is the solution:

```
new ListTile(
        title: Text('签名'),
        trailing: new Container(
          width: 150.0,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: new TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                decoration:
                    new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: '$userAddr'),
              ),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
                color: Colors.black26,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Always using a Expand for textfiled.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, on V1.12 of flutter, you can put a Row in the title and populate it

```
ListTile(
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Text('签名')
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                // your TextField's Content
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
            color: Colors.black26,
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
ListTile(
  title: Text("Price"),
  trailing: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
    child: TextField(),
  ),
),
```